# How to check input file is empty, and also display an alert if png format is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I have got an input file upload , need to check which file is uploaded / if no file is selected by the client using jquery.

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="file1" style="color:White" />
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

The check should trigger when submit is clicked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the sample I have created:

http://jsfiddle.net/G7xke/

---

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="files" id="file1" style="color:White" />
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
<button value="check" id="check" name="check" >check</button>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    var fileName = $("#file1").val();
    if(fileName.lastIndexOf("png")===fileName.length-3)
        alert("OK");
    else
        alert("Not PNG");
})
```

Comment: Note that the form may be submitted using the Enter key (use `.submit`), and the of the file may end in `png` but not be a PNG (check for `.png`)

Comment: but this doesnt check if the client has not selected any thing in the fileupload

Comment: Is it not just checking if `fileName.length===0`? I am not writing your javascript, I am just giving you hints.

Answer (score 5):

Have you made any attempt at doing this?

```
$('input[type="file"]').val()
```

Answer (score 2):

Testing for...

```
$('#file1')[0].files.length == 0
```

...is working for me in Chrome.  The jQuery is actually not even necessary as the raw HTML element (returned by the `[0]` on the jQuery object) gives access to the files list.

Answer (score 0):

This demo works in IE9 + Chrome:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/brdFq/
```

using Jquery, you get the val();

a quick implementation here:

```
function hasFile(selector){
    //if there is a value, return true, else: false;
    return $(selector).val()? true: false;
}
```